# Switching Map Units on Data Frame Properties back to Feet in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, data-frame

Using ArcView 10.1, I cannot switch the Map (Units) nder Data Frame Properties to Feet.  It is currently at Decimal Degrees.  Display can switch.

How do you switch it back to Feet?

Comment: In dataframe you choose properties to change units, it help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLh1VjJH3o8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you must have your coordinate system set to a system that uses feet as its units.

Answer (score 1):

Your data frame is probably set to a Geographic Coordinate System on its Coordinate System tab. Try changing it to a Projected Coordinate System which has feet units.