# Entering Track from Garmin to GIS not getting basemap and orthomap to line up with Track?

Tags: gps

[image]

I collected a GPS path on a flight and I would like to condense the path to the place where we landed and took pictures (condensed area at base of map; I want to delete the other part of the line). Ultimately, I would like to eliminate all of the information except for the location where the flight landed.

When I add the Track to GIS and "zoom to layer," it makes the data frame leader go off the page and the Track does not match up with the basemap.

What is the issue?

Comment: Hey SSAlaska - I think I can see from your screenshot (text is small) that your Data Frame is reading geometry in Feet as the [map units](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83908/how-to-switch-map-units-on-data-frame-properties-back-to-feet-in-arcmap). To my knowledge, GPS path data is loaded out from your gps unit in decimal degrees - maybe change the projection of your data frame to something in decimal degrees?

Answer (score 1):

I would think from what I can see that this is almost certainly a mismatch between the project CRS and the path CRS so that would be my first point to check. If the path data you are loading is a gpx file then the CRS will be WGS 84. I use QGIS rather than Arc but check the CRS the project is in and whether it will change the CRS of your imports 'on the fly' or not.